# Loop script for all values of dropdown

Tags: loops, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

I'm looking to make a script that cycles through a dropdown list and creates a pdf for each.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HrXWkNXT7aEWOXkngiuSX9Sr1F0V4Y_rZH6Eg3mjaJQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Screenshot]

First I would like to check if B2 is not empty, then if so create pdf and change A2 to the next option until all are complete. I have a basic script but feel free to disregard!

```
function loopScript() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const interface = ss.getSheetByName("Interface");
  
  var folderID = "###GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER ID###";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  
  const exportOptions =  'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' 
    + '&size=A4'                      
    + '&portrait=true'               
    + '&scale=4'            
    + '&fith=true&source=labnol'         
    + '&top_margin=0.05'
    + '&bottom_margin=0.05'
    + '&left_margin=1.00'
    + '&right_margin=0.25'
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
    + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'
    + '&fzr=false'                       
    + '&gid=125740569';                        
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();

  const nameFile =  "NAME OF FILE" + ".pdf" ;
  folder.createFile(response.setName(nameFile));
  DriveApp.createFile(response.setName(nameFile));
  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal from `First I would like to check if B2 is not empty, then if so create pdf and change A2 to the next option until all are complete.`. Can I ask you about the detail of both your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Step 1: Make sure B2 isn't empty |
IF B2 <> "" |
Step 2: Make PDF of current sheet (Interface) |
Step 3: Change A2 to the next option |
Loop |

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Step 3: Change A2 to the next option | Loop` and your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: That is OK, I will try my best to explain! I have 4 options: "Joe, Barry, Jane, Fred". I would like the script to run for each of those options

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's help, I ended up using Tanaike's advice and continued on to come up with this:

```
function sendAll() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var interface = ss.getSheetByName("Interface");
var range = interface.getRange("A2");                                                               
// Cell of validation
const values = [...new Set(range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues() 
[0].getValues().flat())];   // Gets array of validation
var first = values[0];                                                                              
// 1st cell of validation
var number = values.length - 1;                                                                     
// Length of validation
range.setValue(first);                                                                              
// Sets value to first one

for(i = 0;i < number;i++) {                                                                           
// Loop number of names
if (interface.getRange("B2").getValue().length > 0) {                                             
// Sheet isn't empty
var person = interface.getRange("A2").getValue();
const url = 'MY SHEET URL';

var folderID = "MY FOLDER ID";
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

const exportOptions =  'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' 
+ '&size=A4'                      
+ '&portrait=true'               
+ '&scale=4'            
+ '&fith=true&source=labnol'         
+ '&top_margin=0.05'
+ '&bottom_margin=0.05'
+ '&left_margin=1.00'
+ '&right_margin=0.25'
+ '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
+ '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'
+ '&fzr=false'                       
+ '&gid=0';    

var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ 
ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();

const nameFile =  person + ".pdf" ;
folder.createFile(response.setName(nameFile));
DriveApp.createFile(response.setName(nameFile));   

const nextValue = values[values.indexOf(range.getValue()) + 1] || values[0];
range.setValue(nextValue);
}
else {const nextValue = values[values.indexOf(range.getValue()) + 1] || 
values[0];
range.setValue(nextValue);}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check the cell "B2". When the cell "B2" is not empty, you want to set the value of the dropdown list of cell "A2" to the next value of the list.
- For example, when the dropdown list is `Joe, Barry, Jane, Fred` and the cell "A2" is `Barry`, you want to set the cell to `Jane`.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const interface = ss.getSheetByName("Interface");
```

##### To:

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const interface = ss.getSheetByName("Interface");
if (interface.getRange("B2").isBlank()) return;
const range = interface.getRange("A2");
const values = [...new Set(range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat())];
const nextValue = values[values.indexOf(range.getValue()) + 1] || values[0];
range.setValue(nextValue);
```

- In this modified script, when the cell "B2" is empty, the script is finished. When the cell "B2" is not empty, the script is run and the cell "A2" is updated and your script for creating the PDF file is run.

#### Note:

- In above modified script, when the dropdown list is `Joe, Barry, Jane, Fred` and the cell "A2" is `Fred`, the value of `Joe` is set. If you want to change this, please modify the above script.
- In your current script, `url` is not defined. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)
- [getDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidation)
- [getCriteriaValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#getcriteriavalues)

Comment: Thank you! This is VERY close. If B2 is empty, I don't want the script to stop, but move onto the next A2 value. I think I can make this work though!

Comment: @Alistair McEvoy Thank you for replying. From `If B2 is empty, I don't want the script to stop, but move onto the next A2 value.`, in this case, how about removing the line of `if (interface.getRange("B2").isBlank()) return;`? If I misunderstood your actual goal, I apologize.

Comment: We are so close, thank you. I need the script to run 3 times. One time with Joe, then nextValue = Barry, then nextValue = Jane, then nextValue = Fred. The script should only run with Joe, Barry and Jane because when Fred is the value, B2 is blank. If I add more names, I will need it to run more times

Comment: @Alistair McEvoy Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new request of `I need the script to run 3 times. One time with Joe, then nextValue = Barry, then nextValue = Jane, then nextValue = Fred. The script should only run with Joe, Barry and Jane because when Fred is the value, B2 is blank. If I add more names, I will need it to run more times`.

Comment: How do I make 

"if (interface.getRange("B2").isBlank()) return;
const range = interface.getRange("A2");
const values = [...new Set(range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat())];
const nextValue = values[values.indexOf(range.getValue()) + 1] || values[0];
range.setValue(nextValue);"

Execute for every Value in A2

Comment: @Alistair McEvoy Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `How do I make "if (interface.getRange("B2").isBlank()) return; const range = interface.getRange("A2"); const values = [...new Set(range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat())]; const nextValue = values[values.indexOf(range.getValue()) + 1] || values[0]; range.setValue(nextValue);" Execute for every Value in A2`, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the detail of your new request?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following:

- For each dropdown in `A2`, check if the formula in `B2` populates any values (based on data from sheet `Data`).
- If any value is populated in `B` due to the formula, create a `PDF` file using the value of `A2` for the file name (you have achieved this already).

#### Method 1:

In this case, I'd suggest the following workflow:

- Retrieve an array with the accepted `values` from `A2` dropdown (you can use the method used in [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278556)).
- Iterate through these `values`, and for each one, set the `A2` value, using [Range.setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)).
- Call [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) in order to update the data in `B2` according to the current value in `A2`.
- Check if `B2` is blank (using [Range.isBlank](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank), for example).
- If `B2` is not blank, create the drive file.

```
function loopScript() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const interface = ss.getSheetByName("Interface");
  const range = interface.getRange("A2");
  const values = [...new Set(range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat())].filter(String);
  values.forEach(name => {
    range.setValue(name);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    if (!interface.getRange("B2").isBlank()) {
      // CODE FOR CREATING FILE
    }
  });
}
```

#### Method 2:

In the previous method, `setValue`, `flush`, `getRange` and `isBlank` are used iteratively, greatly increasing the amount of calls to the spreadsheet. This is not the best practice, as it will slow down the script (see [Minimize calls to other services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services)), and this will get worse if there are more valid options for the dropdown.

Therefore, since the data this formula is using can be found in sheet `Data`, I'd suggest using that source data instead of the formula, in order to minimize the calls to the spreadsheet.

In this case, you could follow this workflow:

- Get all data in `Data` at once using [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Get all valid options in the data validation from `A2`, as in method 1.
- For each option, check if there's any row in `Data` that has this option in column `A` and a non-empty cell in `B`.
- If there is some data for that option, create the file.

```
function loopScript() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const interface = ss.getSheetByName("Interface");
  const data = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const DATA_FIRST_ROW = 2;
  const dataValues = data.getRange(DATA_FIRST_ROW,1,data.getLastRow()-DATA_FIRST_ROW+1,2).getValues();
  const range = interface.getRange("A2");
  const values = [...new Set(range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat())].filter(String);
  values.forEach(name => {
    const optionValues = dataValues.filter(dataRow => dataRow[0] === name);
    const nonEmpty = optionValues.some(optionValue => optionValue[1] !== "");
    if (nonEmpty) {
      // CODE FOR CREATING FILE
    }
  });
}
```